# context for onReceive function is not working properly when the app is not running

Tags: android, push-notification, android-context, android-c2dm

I am developing an application that will show the push notification messages. When I am trying to display the messages using Toast message, then it is working properly at any situations. But I want to use `StatusBarNotifications` for these push notifications. It is working fine, when the app is running. If I restarted the device after shutting down, the statusbar notification is not showing. This is the same case when the app is force closed.

How can I solve this issue?

The following are the code :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{ 
  if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"))
  {
    handleMessage(context, intent);
  }
}
private void handleMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    String message= intent.getStringExtra("msg");
     Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"\n message : "+message,1).show();
     NotificationManager objNotfManager=(NotificationManager)  context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int icon = R.drawable.logo;
    CharSequence tickerMessage = message;
    long when= System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification objNotf = new Notification(icon,tickerMessage,when);
     CharSequence title = "New message from "+message;
    CharSequence mesage = "You have "+number+" unread messages";
    Intent NotifIntent  = new Intent( context.getApplicationContext(),TabContainer.class);
    NotifIntent.putExtra("message",message);
    PendingIntent contentIntent  = PendingIntent.getActivity(  context.getApplicationContext(), 0, NotifIntent, 0);
    objNotf.setLatestEventInfo(  context.getApplicationContext(), title, mesage, contentIntent);
            objNotfManager.notify(1,objNotf);
}
```

Previously I used with context, but it was not working for other widgets, other the Toast. so I planned to use `context.getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921464/android-context-has-some-problem-when-displaying-push-notification-using-c2dm/8974369#8974369

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: use `getBaseContext()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

(Semi) Detailed Answer:

I figured out an answer to your problem as i had the same problem today.
the problem is that when your app is force-closed/after restart and isn't sitting in the task manager, `getApplicationContext()` isn't properly initialized. Using it will give you bad references when trying to retrieve the notification manager to generate a notification.

There is a good chance that the `Context` that is passed to your handleMessage method is given by `getApplicationContext()` too.

The context that is available to you when your application is not alive can be retrieved with `getBaseContext()`

What i would suggest is to trace back as far as possible through the methods to the place where the push notification intent gets received, and change whatever `Context` that gets passed down to the handleMessage method, and replace it with `Context context = getBaseContext();` and then you can use the context parameter within the method.